# Get transactionID string with Transaction object

Tags: transactions, solana-client

I currently have a buffer that I deserialized into a [Transaction Object](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Transaction.html). I need the transaction ID to search on lets say Solscan.

Answer (score 1):

The `Transaction` is really the *request*. It does not carry the *response*, i.e. the transaction signature.

Transaction signature is only returned from one of the send transaction methods, e.g. [`Connection.sendTransaction()`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#sendTransaction).

I am not aware of a mechanism to give you the transaction signature, given the original transaction object, especially since the same transaction can be sent to the chain multiple times (as long as far apart from each other so  not to get dropped as a duplicate).